# Wireless Issue Macbook Air

Tags: wireless, macbook-air

I have Ubuntu downloaded on a usb and when I start it up, I cannot get my wifi to turn on. I have already been to system settings to try to turn on the Broadcom but it just stays on **do not use selection** after applying.

Comment: Please post the output of `lspci`.

Comment: If you need an offline guide please post the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.